# app.config connection string does not work

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

this piece of code works fine....

```
Private Sub save()
        Dim con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\Chuttu VB\Projects\LIC\LIC.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True")

        Dim sql As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ProposerDetails " & _
                                            "VALUES (" & Convert.ToInt32(PolicyNumberTextBox.Text) & ",'" & NameTextBox.Text & "','" & AgeTextBox.Text & "','" & PhoneTextBox.Text & "','" & AddressTextBox.Text & "','" _
                                            & NomineeTextBox.Text & "','" & NomineeRelationTextBox.Text & "'," & PlanID() & ",'" & PolicyTermTextBox.Text & "','" & PremiumAmountTextBox.Text & "','" _
                                            & PremiumTypeComboBox.Text & "','" & SumProposedTextBox.Text & "','Date' )", con)

        MsgBox(sql.CommandText)
        con.Open()

        MsgBox(con.State.ToString)
        Dim i As Integer = sql.ExecuteNonQuery
        MsgBox(i.ToString)
        con.Close()
        sql.Dispose()
        con.Dispose()
        ToolStripStatusLabelMessage.Text = "Saved"
    End Sub
```

as soon as i change the connection string to the connection string from app.config it stops working(adding data to DB)

```
Private Sub save()
        Dim con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(LIC.My.Settings.LICConnectionString)

        Dim sql As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ProposerDetails " & _
                                            "VALUES (" & Convert.ToInt32(PolicyNumberTextBox.Text) & ",'" & NameTextBox.Text & "','" & AgeTextBox.Text & "','" & PhoneTextBox.Text & "','" & AddressTextBox.Text & "','" _
                                            & NomineeTextBox.Text & "','" & NomineeRelationTextBox.Text & "'," & PlanID() & ",'" & PolicyTermTextBox.Text & "','" & PremiumAmountTextBox.Text & "','" _
                                            & PremiumTypeComboBox.Text & "','" & SumProposedTextBox.Text & "','Date' )", con)

        MsgBox(sql.CommandText)
        con.Open()

        MsgBox(con.State.ToString)
        Dim i As Integer = sql.ExecuteNonQuery
        MsgBox(i.ToString)
        con.Close()
        sql.Dispose()
        con.Dispose()
        ToolStripStatusLabelMessage.Text = "Saved"
    End Sub
```

NOTE: I get no errors.

Comment: Your 2 code examples look identical and you use a hard coded connection string in both.  Also just as tip, you are leaving yourself open to SQL injection forming your query in that fashion.  Use those SQL parameters!

Comment: the connection string in the second one is not hard coded...i am pulling it from the app.config file.

Comment: @Etch Can i add an  INSERT query in the dataset(.xsd file) and use it to insert data ?? If yes then how?? How do i pass values to the parameters used in the INSERT query??

Comment: @SunnyBhattacharjee: The connection strings are different.  Maybe the second one (the one in the config file) is incorrect?  Or am I just not familiar with some connection string syntax about the file location?

Comment: @David I have changed the connection string for the second code.

Comment: @SunnyBhattacharjee: What else is different, then?  When you step through the code in the debugger, are the object states all identical?  Are the connection strings identical at runtime?  Can you profile the database to watch the commands that get sent to it and see if they're identical?

Comment: @David The codes executes and dose not throw any error or exception...but data is not saved.

Comment: @SunnyBhattacharjee: There's more to debugging than that.  Stepping through the debugger can reveal to you the runtime values of things so you can see what's changed.  This will help you narrow down problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a short deal explanation.

This is how you use a connection string from the config file.

```
Dim sqlConn as SqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("myConnectionString").ConnectionString)
```

[Here is a link to how to do a parameterized queries](http://www.shotdev.com/aspnet/vbnet-system-data-sqlclient/vbnet-system-data-sqlclient-parameter-query-sqlparameter/)

Comment: to use your connection string,do i need to import something??? because i get only configuration in intellisense  and not ConfigurationManager

Answer (score 0):

Try changing LIC.My.Settings.LICConnectionString
to ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LICConnectionString"].ConnectionString

Comment: to use your connection string,do i need to import something??? because i get only configuration in intellisense  and not ConfigurationManager